# Explain C Macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#define MAX(a,b) ((dx > dy) ? dx : dy)
```

Would anyone mind breaking down the ((dx > dy) ? dx : dy) part?
This comes from console lessons 1-60.

Comment: Which part, the `>` or the `?`?

Comment: -1 That does not appear to be real code (arguments a b not used).

Comment: This question isn't even really related to the preprocessor. Just to a basic C operation

Answer (score 7):

It is roughly equivalent to:

```
int MAX (int dx, int dy)
{
  if (dx > dy)
    return dx;
  else
    return dy;
}
```

It is also not correct.  It should be:

```
#define MAX(a,b) ((a)>(b))?(a):(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the [Ternary operator.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Vala.2C_Objective-C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript.2C_ActionScript)

Answer (score 1):

As written, the line doesn't make sense to me.  But

```
#define MAX(a, b)  ((a > b) ? a : b)
```

translates roughly, in pseudocode, to

```
#define MAX(a,b)  if (a > b) then a else b
```

Comment: it should be noted that the () around each thing passed to the macro is important as you could easily go MAX(1>2=2,2) and it would translate to:  if (1>2=2 > b) { return 1>2=2; } else { return b; } which is invalid code.

Comment: @graphitemaster: Yes, you should always over-parenthesize macro arguments to limit nasty (and hard-to-debug) side-effects.  I kept it simple for clarity, but code like my example should never make it to production.  Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

`test ? expr1 : expr2` is the ternary operator. This expression evaluates to `expr1` if `test` is true and to `expr2` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It means that if dx is greater then dy then select dx, otherwise select dy.

Answer (score 0):

```
int MAX (int dx, int dy)
{
  if (dx > dy)
    return dx;
  else
    return dy;
}
```